# How do I recursively determine the maximum number of children that any vertex in a tree has?

Tags: tree, pseudocode

```
function countChildren(node)  
    i=0
    m=0
    node = LMCHILD(node)
    while (w is not nil)  
        m = max{countChildren(node), m};
        w = RMSIB(w);
        i++;

    return max{i,m}
```

I have this so far, but I am tracing it and it doesnt work and I dont understand why. How can I make this recursive if i and m both get reset to 0 every time a recursive call is made

Comment: Should that be `w = LMCHILD(node)`?

Comment: Resetting `m` to `0` shouldn't be a problem, because the loop updates it.